# Is there a way to use coordinates to select an element in iOS UI Test Automation?

Tags: ios, swift, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm dealing with a `UICollectionView` that has many elements. One of them, it's a `UISuplementaryView` that contains many clickable cells (it's a calendar).

When I do `po print(debugDescription)` I get many elements of type "other" that look like this
`Other 0x7f8a4cb06e30: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, -1175.5}, {50.0, 38.0}}`
Does anyone know if there is a way to use these coordinates to interact with the element?

Answer (score 1):

First try to assign the elements accessibility traits before dropping down to the coordinate API. In your *production* code, set `accessibilityIdentifier` on the `UISupplementaryView`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    reusableView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Reusable View \(indexPath.row)"
    return reusableView
}
```

Then, in UI Testing, interact with it via:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.otherElements["Reusable View 3"].tap()
```